# Autosys. Is there a condition for NOT failed and NOT Running?

Tags: autosys

We have a process that depends on daily and weekly imports.   All we care about the weekly files are not failed not currently running.   Is this possible in Autosys?

I looked through the Autosys documentation but I did not find anything like this.  I am guessing there is maybe a trick that I am not thinking of to do this.

Comment: "All we care about the weekly files are not failed not currently running" - is this another autosys job that does this?

Answer (score 0):

For anybody that see this later the trick to use success and not running dependency in an or.

```
(s(**jobname**) or n(**jobname**))
```